# Как доступ к элементам класса по индексам?

Tags: python, классы, list, методы

Как сделать доступ к элементам класса Point в классе Vector, я что-то упускаю. Пишет ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 39, in __getitem__
TypeError: 'Point' object is not subscriptable
```

Код:

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__x = None
        self.__y = None
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if (type(x) == int) or (type(x) == float):
            self.__x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        if (type(y) == int) or (type(y) == float):
            self.__y = y


class Vector:
    def __init__(self, coordinates: Point):
            self.coordinates = coordinates
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.coordinates[index] = value
        
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.coordinates[index]
```

Comment: М.б. вы хотели `self.coordinates = [coordinates]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В классе вектора вы неправильно объявили словарь, для того, чтобы индексировать элементы

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__x = None
        self.__y = None
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.__x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, (int, float)):
            self.__x = x

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self.__y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y):
        if isinstance(y, (int, float)):
            self.__y = y


class Vector:
    def __init__(self, point: Point):
            self.coordinates = {0: point}
            
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        self.coordinates[index] = value
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.coordinates[index]
```

Comment: Заодно уж напишите, что тип лучше не через `type(...) == ...` проверять, а через `isinstance`

Comment: @CrazyElf точно, спасибо за подсказку)

Comment: Ещё `isinstance` хорош тем, что можно короче тоже самое написать: `isinstance(y, (int, float)):`, то есть возможные типы можно сразу кортежем один раз написать )

Comment: @CrazyElf К базовым типам да, но вот когда уже есть многоуровневое приложение, то это не совсем удобно) Проще декоратором оформить это